# Trying to upgrade Conda

Tags: macos, anaconda, spyder, conda

I'm trying to teach myself Python using Spyder.  I have the Anaconda distribution of python 2.7 and 3.6. I defined two conda environments, one for python 2.7 and one for python 3.6. All has worked well for the past few months. Recently when trying to upgrade a package like numpy, using `conda upgrade numpy` , I get the message:

```
 ==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.5.4
  latest version: 4.5.8

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base conda'
```

When I run the above command it appears all is working until I get to the proceed question after a list of upgrades, after I say yes to proceed I get 21 error messages related to CondaVerificationError and 2 related to 'ClobberError:'.

If I ignore the warning about upgrading conda, I get a similar but smaller set of error messages.

I tried updating some packages using pip and it worked fine but if I run `conda upgrade package` just to check, conda wants to upgrade the new package but again tells me I need to upgrade conda.  If I try to upgrade conda using pip, it tells me the older version of conda is the latest and stops. So at this point I don't know if pip is really updating the packages or not.  And I hate to proceed when I can't upgrade anything using conda. Does anyone know what's wrong or how to upgrade conda? I'm running High Sierra on my older iMac.

Comment: What happens if you just create a new conda env with the list of packages you want - does that work without errors? I'm fairly sure your solution is not going to involve pip (this would be a "Now you have two problems…" situation.)

Comment: conda works ok now but it keeps giving me the warning to upgrade conda.